# Ignore duplicate messages in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

We have one use case where we need to ignore duplicate messages (custom logic for duplication) from kafka. Is it possible that in a stream all the  messages having same kafka header key/or based on some logic can be reduced to one message which is latest in the kafka topic. Eg : if we receive 10 messages of same key then My cloud stream handler should get only 10th message.

Right now we are doing it manually by maintain a set of messages for the messages that have been successfully processed. This set will act as a cache to track processed messages and identify duplicates.